# How to compile a Spark job for Cloud Dataproc that reads CSV files from GCS?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm trying to use Google Cloud Dataproc to run a Spark ML job on CSV files stored in GCS. But, I'm having trouble figuring out how to compile the fat JAR for submission.

I can tell from the docs that cloud dataproc nodes have the connector pre-installed, but I don't know how to add the connector to my SBT config so I can develop and compile a fat JAR locally to submit to dataproc. Is there a line I can add to my `build.sbt` so I have access to the connector locally (i.e. so it will compile)? And mark as "provided" if necessary so that it doesn't conflict with the version pre-installed on the worker nodes?

Any pointers or examples would be super appreciated.

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reference the connector explicitly in build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.google.cloud.bigdataoss" % "gcs-connector" % "1.6.1-hadoop2" % "provided"
```

Note that this is the unshaded version of the library. On Dataproc clusters, the shaded artifact is provided and this artifact can be found on maven central with the 'shaded' classifier:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.google.cloud.bigdataoss" % "gcs-connector" % "1.6.1-hadoop2" % "provided" classifier "shaded"
```

For development, you may be able to get away with just using the Hadoop FileSystem interfaces and when deploying to Dataproc using paths of the form 'gs://[bucket]/[path/to/object]' instead of local paths.

Comment: Thanks! So should I develop using the shaded or unshaded version, or neither? Sounds like you're saying neither, that I should just use local files for development and then rely on the knowledge that the GCS connector will be on the cluster (so just deploy with gs:// paths). There's nothing I need to import (or have in my build.sbt) to make that work?

Comment: That's what I normally do - use org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem with local files and drop in a gs:// path via job arguments when I deploy. There are some differences between local and GCS paths that come up if you're doing something out of the ordinary (e.g., building a write-ahead log like HBase's) and metadata operations will be slower when using GCS when compared to HDFS or local files, but there's little difference for normal MR/Spark jobs.